# Ubuntu Unwanted Suspends

Tags: suspend, 15.10

Ubuntu 15.10 suspends while I am in the middle of something. What may cause this problem and how to solve it?

---

[image: Power Settings]

Comment: How often have you set Ubuntu to suspend and once you wake it up again does it suspend in the amount of time that you have set? Because it could just be the system not realising that there is activity.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda - I haven't check if it suspends in 10 minutes or not, if it happens again I will post the results. I added image of power settings to question.